# Batch find, clean and output

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find

I have a file like this:

```
       {
        "id": 33,
        "time_base": "1/1000",
        "start": 41200605,
        "start_time": "41200.605000",
        "end": 42180534,
        "end_time": "42180.534000",
        "tags": {
            "title": "Chapter 34"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 34,
        "time_base": "1/1000",
        "start": 42180534,
        "start_time": "42180.534000",
        "end": 44248038,
        "end_time": "44248.038000",
        "tags": {
            "title": "Chapter 35"
        }
    },
```

and I need to output the results of the end_time for each entry. So I have this

```
find "end_time" time.txt >endtime.txt
```

Which does find them but outputs the whole line.

```
---------- endtime.txt        
        "end_time": "42180.534000",
        "end_time": "44248.038000",
```

Is there a clean way to just have the numerals of the output.

```
42180.534000
44248.038000
```

Comment: use a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop to dissect the line(s) with proper `tokens` and `delims`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options for you:

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) using `If`:

```bat
@For /F UseBackTokens^=2^,4Delims^=^" %%A In ("time.txt")Do @If /I "%%A"=="end_time" Echo(%%B
```

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) using `Find.exe`:

```bat
@For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %%A In ('Find /I "end_time"^<"time.txt" 2^>NUL')Do @Echo(%%A
```

From [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) using `If`:

```bat
For /F UseBackTokens^=2^,4Delims^=^" %A In ("time.txt")Do @If /I "%A"=="end_time" Echo(%B
```

From [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) using `Find.exe`:

```bat
For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %A In ('Find /I "end_time"^<"time.txt" 2^>NUL')Do @Echo(%A
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a few crappy attempts at for loop with Tokens and Delims but could never get it to work correctly or at all and didn't want to have a wall of failed code in the question. This works great and i now understand it better then the examples I was looking at. thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There might be another option. This is -almost- a valid JSON file. It could be wrapped with one line at the beginning and one additional line at the end. Perhaps the creator of this file would be willing to make it a valid JSON file.

=== time.txt

```
{   "records": [
        {
            "id": 33,
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start": 41200605,
            "start_time": "41200.605000",
            "end": 42180534,
            "end_time": "42180.534000",
            "tags": {
                "title": "Chapter 34"
            }
        }
        ,{
            "id": 34,
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start": 42180534,
            "start_time": "42180.534000",
            "end": 44248038,
            "end_time": "44248.038000",
            "tags": {
                "title": "Chapter 35"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This file can be read as a JSON file. If you are on a supported Windows platform, it will have PowerShell.

```
PS 09:00  C:\src\json
>(Get-Content -Path .\time.txt  | ConvertFrom-Json).records.end_time | Out-File -PSPath '.\endtime.txt' -Encoding ascii
PS 09:01  C:\src\json
>type .\endtime.txt
42180.534000
44248.038000
```

This can be run from a cmd.exe shell using:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-Content -Path .\time.txt |" ^
    "ConvertFrom-Json).records.end_time |" ^
    "Out-File -PSPath '.\endtime.txt' -Encoding ascii"
```